# DAX Internal Date Hierarchy Behavior

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Hoping someone can explain the difference in the behavior of ALL between these 2 cases:

case1: referencing the entire Date table in ALL - gives the correct result

[image]

case2: specifically referencing the date column from the Date table in ALL - gives the wrong result, why?

[image]

Date table just looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to microsoft document:
ALL(table) - Removes all filters from the specified table.

Where as ALL(Column) variant is useful when you want to remove the context filters for one or more specific columns and to keep all other context filters. All column arguments must come from the same table

For more details, please visit - [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/all-function-dax#:~:text=ALL()%20can%20only%20be,not%20to%20return%20a%20table.&text=Removes%20all%20filters%20from%20the%20specified%20table.&text=All%20column%20arguments%20must%20come,keep%20all%20other%20context%20filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/all-function-dax#:%7E:text=ALL()%20can%20only%20be,not%20to%20return%20a%20table.&text=Removes%20all%20filters%20from%20the%20specified%20table.&text=All%20column%20arguments%20must%20come,keep%20all%20other%20context%20filters).

Comment: thanks, I guess it's confusing in this case because the table only has one column anyway. Wouldn't you expect both variants to return the same result in that case?